# How to identify ExtJS elements for Coded UI window resize test

Tags: extjs, visual-studio-2013, coded-ui-tests

I am starting to use Coded UI in Visual Studio to test an ExtJS app's interface, and tests fail when I have a resize or drag/drop action on an ExtJS modal window with the following error:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotVisibleException: The control is not visible.
```

My suspicion is that the target control for the stop location is an id that is generated by ext, which changes. Also, I don't know what panel is going to be behind the modal I'm resizing, so I can't just put an id on it. Is there a way to set the stop location relative to the viewport?

I haven't been able to find much documentation on using Coded UI with ExtJS; if anyone has experience with this I would appreciate a point in the right direction. Thanks!